# User displayName validation with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, validation, firebase-authentication

I allow my users to modify their displayName by an input field and I would like the Firebase to validate it, avoiding bad characters like html code or similar. Firebase has a built-in input validation tool for email address, does it have for displayName also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a HTTPS Callable Cloud Function trigger that can be called from your application and updates the user's info. Then keep and update the user profile in the realtime database to take advantage of the database rules to ensure the data is validated.

If the display name for example didn't meet the criteria, the database update operation would return permission denied with an error code of 1.

A successful write operation to the realtime database would mean a valid display name at which point you could go ahead with updating the user's info via the Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: Upvoted for the basic approach. Nothing keeps the users from calling the API to update their display name in the code, so you shouldn't rely on that value following your custom rules. The database value in this answer *would* follow those rules.